# Syntax error: ')' expected, but I cannot find where

Tags: compiler-errors, pattern-matching, syntax-error, ocaml

Here is my code:

```
type noeud = Lettre of (char * bool * arbre_lex)
and arbre_lex = noeud list

exception Deja_defini of string



let rec ajoute mot arbre n =
    if existe mot arbre then raise (Deja_defini mot) else
    match arbre with
        | [] ->
            begin
                if n+1 = String.length mot then [ Lettre( mot.[n] , true , [] ) ]
                else [ Lettre ( mot.[n] , false, ajoute mot arbre (n+1) ) ]
            end
        | head::tail ->
            begin
                match head with 
                    | Lettre (mot.[n], b, a) -> (*line 19, source of error*)
                        begin
                            if n+1 = String.length mot then [ Lettre ( mot.[n] , true , a ) ]::tail 
                            else [ Lettre ( mot.[n] , b , ajoute mot a (n+1) ) ]::tail
                        end
                    | Lettre (_, b, a) -> ajoute mot tail n
            end
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
$ocamlc -o main *.ml
File "main.ml", line 19, characters 21-22:
Error: Syntax error: ')' expected
File "main.ml", line 19, characters 17-18:
Error: This '(' might be unmatched
```

Now I know I can improve my code, and I can include the second match in the first one, however, **I'm specifically interested in finding the source of the error**. I tried a lot of things, but none of them seemed to change the error.

So feel free to post improvements, but I'm mostly interested into how I can run this exact code to help avoid the error in the future.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a valid pattern: `mot.[n]`. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with it, or what the compiler thinks it is given the error.

Comment: I was trying to use the short version of String.get mot s, as shown here https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/String.html

Comment: That's also not a valid pattern, of course, but I think I understand what you're trying to do. I'll explain in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntactic construct on the left side of the arrow is not an ordinary expression, but a pattern. For convenience it looks very much like an expression, but it behaves very differently. It is also purely a compile time construct.

For example, the pattern `a`, like in `Lettre (_, b, a)` will not evaluate to the value of `a`, or match the value at the position of `a` against the value of an existing binding named `a`. Instead it will make a new binding named `a` that refer to the value at the position of `a`, and shadow any previous binding of that name.

So if, for example, the value you are matching against is `Lettre ('a', true, [])`, `a` will, on the right side of the arrow, refer to the value `[]`. And `b` will refer to `true`.

Outside of being a convenient syntax for binding values to names in patterns, not allowing runtime values in patterns allows the compiler to make guarantees about the exhaustiveness of a pattern match as well as to optimize it at compile time. If runtime values were allowed in patterns you would always have to provide a wildcard pattern to catch the rest of the possibilities since you won't be able to know at compile time which possibilities might match at runtime.

I hope you see now why it doesn't make sense to allow expressions like `mot.[n]`, or even a name bound to the value of `mot.[n]`, in patterns.

However, there is a construct, separate from a pattern, that allows runtime conditions to be used in pattern matching, called "guards" or "when" clauses. Using your example:

```
match head with 
    | Lettre (ch, b, a) when ch = mot.[n] -> ...
```

This does require a case with a wildcard in place of `ch` to cover all the cases that the guard does not match. But since you already have that you should be good.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand it now. I was hoping mot.[n] would be transformed to a character, which would then be used for the pattern matching, but it seems that *when* is the way to go to do that.